# Difference in pattern matching with an without label in visitor in Rascal

Tags: pattern-matching, visitor-pattern, rascal

In Rascal, why is it that pattern matching behaves differntly with and without label (at least in a visitor)? I wrote the following two visitors visiting the same parse tree t. The first one prints "test" three times, which is correct in my opinion as there are three occurrences of "ParseCond" in the parse tree (I checked this by rendering the tree and performing visual inspection). The second visitor, however, prints "test" many more times.

Is this behaviour I should have expected? Or might this behaviour be documented poorly? Or might it even be a bug?

First visitor:

```
visit(t) {
    case IfCond: print("test");
}
```

Second visitor (note the subtle difference: there is a label "i" after "IfCond"):

```
visit(t) {
    case IfCond i: print("test");
}
```

The below code,

```
module t::Test

import ParseTree;
import t::SyntaxTest;

int countCmplFacts() {
    Tree t = parse(#start[ClassDecl], |project://X++Analyzer/Test.xpp|);
    int i = 0;
    visit(t) {
        case CmplFact: {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int countCmplFacts2() {
    Tree t = parse(#start[ClassDecl], |project://X++Analyzer/Test.xpp|);
    int i = 0;
    visit(t) {
        case CmplFact f: {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

with the grammer below,

```
module t::SyntaxTest

layout Layout           = Whitespace* !>> Whitespace;
lexical Whitespace      = [\ \t\n\r];

start syntax ClassDecl  = ClassHeader LeftbrSym DclStmt RightbrSym;
syntax ClassHeader      = Class StdId;

syntax DclStmt          = Decl AsgClause;
syntax Decl             = DeclType StdId;

syntax AsgClause        = AsgSym CmplFact;
syntax CmplFact         = IntSym;
lexical IntSym          = [0-9]+;

lexical Class           = ClassSym !>> [a-zA-Z0-9];
keyword ClassSym        = "class";
lexical StdId           = ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*) !>> [a-zA-Z0-9];
lexical LeftbrSym       = "{";
lexical RightbrSym      = "}";
syntax DeclType         = IntTypeSym !>> [a-zA-Z0-9];
keyword IntTypeSym      = "int";
lexical AsgSym          = "=";
```

shows the difference in behaviour of cases with and without label, when applied to a file containing the below code snippet.

```
class A
{
    int a = 0
}
```

countCmplFacts returns 1711, while countCmplFacts2 returns 1 (which is the correct value in this case in my opinion).

Comment: That sounds like a bug, we'll take a look and post more info after we take a look at it.

Comment: could you post a more complete code example which we could run?

Comment: I edited my question to contain a more concrete example, @jurgenv.

Comment: Ok now it's clear ! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code actually matches *any* value:

```
 case CmplFact:
```

is equivalent to this:

```
 case x:
```

or

```
 case value x:
```

Apparently there are 1711 (nested) values in the given parse tree!

But the alternative pattern is different:

```
 case CmplFact f
```

It matches and binds any `f`, but only if it is of type `CmplFact`, in this case only one.

Comment: find out what `case x` matches by printing it all: `println(x);` :-)

Comment: Wow, I never thought of the possibility what I meant to be a type to match was interpreted as a label. Thanks for your help!  For reference: the Rascal tutor clearly states patterns can only be type or untyped variables and not types that are not assigned to a variable as I was trying to use.

This makes me wonder

Comment: 'though: why does e.g. the following example from the tutor work? `case leaf(int N)` Why is this not interpretated as a variable but as a type (constructor) while there is no variable following it? An example like this makes me think an 'unlabeled' type could be a pattern too.

(Sorry for the accidental split. This comment and the one above should have been one)

Comment: In other words: why shouldn't `leaf(int N)` be `leaf(int N) L` or something like that?

Comment: The pattern match expression language has a number of "operators" which can be nested arbitrarily. The most simple ones are just a variable (matches anything) and a typed variable (matching anything of a specific type). Beyond that the next pattern operator is "congruence a.k.a. constructor", such as `leaf(int N)` which matches all trees with name leaf, but only if it has only one child and it has a type int. Then there is list and set matching, deep matching, etc. They can all be combined by nesting, e.g. `branch(branch(leaf(_),leaf(int j)),leaf(int i))` is also a pattern. Hope this helps!